# Платежная система google

Tags: android, платежи

Я делаю приложение, в котором аккаунт *действует по принципу подписки.* С помощью аккаунта пользователь может авторизовываться не только в приложении, но и на сайте. Пользователь должен был оплачивать подписку с помощью платежных систем (QIWI, Paypal, Яндекс.Деньги и т. д). Но недавно узнал, что гугл запрещает использовать платежные системы внутри приложения, кроме своей. Можно ли как-то обойти этот запрет или встроить оплату гугла на сайт?

Comment: я бы делал по простому - с приложения нельзя работать с подпиской. Вся работа с подпиской - с сайта. А в приложении только нужно ввести имя/пароль.

В целом, гугл допускает использование сторонних сервисов оплаты, если покупаются физические вещи/услуги, к примеру пицца или такси.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Использовать платёжку Google Wallet или систему InApp в приложении.

2) Реализовать платёжки через сайт, а в приложении редиректить на страницу оплаты на сайте.

Comment: Вот за второй способ могут теоретически придраться.

Answer (score 1):

Какая разница, какой способ оплаты? Ты у себя на бэк енде должен аккаунту ставить статус подписки, и дальше уже не важно, что на телефоне была оплата через гугл или через ЯД в браузере или перевод через банк.